# Youtube Data v3 Api, Get Request sort

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-data-api

Hey everyone i'm trying to use the v3 Data Youtube API, already have the Request itself and the response looks like this

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-12-07T16:04:40.472Z",
    "displayMessage": "a"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The Problem is that i only want the last Comment and not the whole 200(cant be set lower) my first Idea was to Save the whole Response and Compare it to the next one so i know whats new, but that wont really work out

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list - this suggests that there is a 'maxResults' parameter you can include in your API query - accepting values 1 - 100. Are you using this specific query? Perhaps post some code.

Comment: The lowest amount for the Request seems to be 200 :(                                                   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId=EiEKGFVDcEQ1eWFiTnlSSzNKNDFTNDRMODE1ZxIFL2xpdmU&part=snippet&maxResults=200&fields=eventId%2Citems(snippet(displayMessage%2CpublishedAt))&key=

Comment: Are you using the 'id' filter in your query? The documentation says that MaxResults is not supported when doing this.

Comment: No i'm not using ID the problem is i only want the last single comment and the lowest value for max is 200

Comment: Ok, so you are talking about the Live Streaming API. What you get back are messages, not comments. And yes, as the doc says, "Acceptable values are 200 to 2000, inclusive. The default value is 500."
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list
So, you could get the whole 200, and then sort on the timestamp to get the latest message.

Comment: And thats exactly where i dont know how to do it anymore :D

Comment: Nobody :(? cant get this to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from the comments, I gather you are talking about the Live Streaming API.

What you get back are messages, not comments. And yes, as the [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) says, "Acceptable values are 200 to 2000, inclusive. The default value is 500." So, you could get the whole 200, and then sort on the timestamp to get the latest message.

*How to do that?*

As you are doing this in C#, once you have the json string, you need to use some library such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Once you add a NuGet package reference to this, you will need

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

and say your json string is

```
var json = @"{
  ""items"": [
    {
      ""snippet"": {
        ""publishedAt"": ""2016-12-07T16:04:40.472Z"",
        ""displayMessage"": ""a""
      }
    }
    ,
    {
      ""snippet"": {
        ""publishedAt"": ""2016-12-12T16:04:40.472Z"",
        ""displayMessage"": ""b""
      }
    }
  ]
}";
```

Then, as described in this [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), use JObject.Parse to use LINQ to JSON.

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray items = parsedJson.SelectToken("items") as JArray;
var sortedItems = items.OrderByDescending(item => item["snippet"]["publishedAt"]);
// sortedItems.First() will give you the item with the newest timestamp
```

Have put all of this at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ubQAZV.

Alternately, you can use JsonConvert if you prefer to deserialize to strongly-typed code.
More about it [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Comment: @Matthias-Klaas, did this help?